# what's the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} e^{-k^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have no idea how to compute the tail sum $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} e^{-k^2} $. I tried subtracting the first n items from all but realized that I don't know a way to calculate the first n items.

Comment: Hint: remainder of a convergent series

Comment: Start by asking whether the series converges for $n=1$. If it does converge, what must be true for the tail of the series?

Comment: @AlexR. Oh it turns out so simple... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For non-negative integers $n,j$ we have $$(n+j)^2 \geq  n^2+j$$  by induction on $j$.  Therefore $$0<e^{-(n+j)^2}<e^{-n^2}e^{-j}$$ so $$0< \sum_{k=n}^\infty e^{-k^2}$$ $$ < \sum_{j=0}^\infty e^{-n^2}e^{-j}$$ $$=e^{-n^2}(1-e^{-1})^{-1}.$$ Note that we don't need  "good" upper bounds for the terms, just anything low enough to prove convergence  of the summation to zero as $n \to \infty$  .